# Adding CR's inside of a RichTextString

Tags: apache-poi

Is there a way to force a newline inside of a RichTextString?  I want to force short lines to be on a set of new lines:
   One
   Two
   Three
   Four - but this one can wrap naturally if it wants to (of course)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new line you can use \n wherever you want. For example when writing any cellvalue or cell comment like

```
Hello
World
test
```

you can use

```
 sheet.getRow(2).getCell(2).setCellValue("Hello\nWorld\ntest");
```